How can I shape a Rocky Mountain Glow Maple to be more round?
We have a young Rocky Mountain Glow Bigtooth Maple in our backyard. According to multiple sources (such as this one), the tree grows with an “upright pyramidal shape.”
Is it possible to shape our tree to be more round rather than conal without stunting its growth too much? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Do not attempt - the tree is genetically programmed, if you will, to always grow in an upright pyramidal form. Topping it, which you're suggesting, will result in a large number of possible leaders, all trying to grow straight up - and all weak and prone to breakage as well.
